# How can I configures my raspbian to show console in it's display?

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

I have a touch display (KeDei 3.5 inch SPI TFTLCD version 3.0 20015/12/1) and  a  raspberry pi 2 model B v 1.1.

I downloaded the last Raspbian Stretch Lite image (https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) this type of image  hasn't desktop environment.

Later, I prepared my micro SD card  with Etcher-Portable-1.3.1-x64.exe. Afterward I connected my display to the GPIO connector of the raspberry in correct form. The Raspbian OS has executed well (I know it because when I doing ping to it, I can see it response), but I don't see anything on the display, 
in fact, my touch display is white.

How can I configure my raspbian to show console in it's display?

Comment: Other than creating an SD card and plug in the LCD display, what else have you done to config the LCD? For example, the LCD communicates with RPi via SPI. did you enable the SPI by uncommenting the `/boot/config.txt` setting from `#dtparam=spi=on` to `dtparam=spi=on`. Did you install the driver for the LCD?

Comment: Sorry Ipmvnd, but except for the sites that are explicitly in another language, [Stack Exchange has an English only policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/212479).

Comment: @hcheung Yes,  I did uncommenting the /etc/boot/config.txt and set dtparam=spi=on. I do not kwon how i can  install the driver for the LCD. I am  newbie in raspbian environment

Answer (score 0):

To make your LCD working you should do one of the followings:

1. Install and configure correctly driver for you particular LCD, unless it is officially supported in your Raspbian release (I guess not).
2. Download and write to your SD card patched Raspbian image with kernel pre-patched to work directly with your LCD.

Try to install drivers from [manufacturer's website](http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html). Unfortunately, I don't see any mention of SPI driver to work with version 3.0 hardware, but there is "LCD_show_v6_1_3". May be it is what you are looking for, or earlier releases are included in there, or they are backward compatible.
Try download it and read carefully included documentation. If no luck, then try to contact manufacturer directly to get appropriate driver or image.

Also try to search a solution or ask for help on [Raspberry Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/) (may be somebody else have made this thing to work earlier). For example, look [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124961).

Comment: I  downloading the driver that you mentioned and I will tries to install it.

Comment: @lpmvnd BTW, you also have complete image with drivers there:   IMG "rpi_35_v6_1_2_3_stretch_kernel_4_13_16".

Comment: Thanks, but I wants to learn how can I do it myself.